# Type errors using filter and lambda?

Tags: haskell, filter, lambda

I've just started learning Haskell about a week ago, and am still struggling a lot with type matching with my functions. I am trying to write a function that takes a list and integer n, and removes every nth index from that list. It's problem 16 in [H99: 99 Haskell Problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/11_to_20). Anyways here is the code:

```
dropN :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropN lst n = filter (\x -> ((elemIndex x lst) + 1) `mod` n /= 0, lst)
```

And here are the errors I am receiving:

```
Prelude> :l P10                                                                
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( P10.hs, interpreted )                                                                                                   
P10.hs:34:15:                                                                      
    Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'             
    Relevant bindings include                                                        
       lst :: [a] (bound at P10.hs:34:7)                                              
       dropN :: [a] -> Int -> [a] (bound at P10.hs:34:1)                            
    Probable cause: `filter' is applied to too few arguments                       
    In the expression:                                                               
        filter (\ x -> (elemIndex x lst) `mod` n /= 0, lst)                          
    In an equation for `dropN':                                                        
        dropN lst n = filter (\ x -> (elemIndex x lst) `mod` n /= 0, lst)                                                                                     
P10.hs:34:22:                                                                      
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Bool'                                                  
    with actual type `(a -> Bool, [a])'                                
    Relevant bindings include                                                        
        lst :: [a] (bound at P10.hs:34:7)                                              
        dropN :: [a] -> Int -> [a] (bound at P10.hs:34:1)                            
    In the first argument of `filter', namely                                    
        `(\ x -> (elemIndex x lst) `mod` n /= 0, lst)'                               
    In the expression:                                                               
        filter (\ x -> (elemIndex x lst) `mod` n /= 0, lst)                          
    In an equation for `dropN':                                                        
        dropN lst n = filter (\ x -> (elemIndex x lst) `mod` n /= 0, lst)                                                                                     
P10.hs:34:53:                                                                      
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe Int' with actual type `Int'                
    In the second argument of `mod', namely `n'                                    
    In the first argument of `(/=)', namely `(elemIndex x lst) `mod` n'        
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: using `elemIndex` to determine the current element's index is not robust since it will return `Just` the index of the *first* element that is equal to the one you are looking for (or `Nothing` if no such element exists), which is not necessarily the index of the element you are currently considering.  Imagine what will happen if you try to run your algorithm on a list of identical values.

Comment: Did you try to understand the error message (it can be a little intimidating)? It can help to break your function out into smaller functions, giving each a type signature, and working within ghci and using `:t` to get the types of different expressions as you go

Answer (score 2):

What you are passing to `filter` is a tuple (pair) consisting of the filtering function and the list. The type of `filter` is

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Therefore you should pass two arguments to `filter`:

```
dropN lst n = filter (\x -> ((elemIndex x lst) + 1) `mod` n /= 0) lst
```

In Haskell, you pass arguments to a function by *seperating them with spaces*. For example,

```
f a b
```

means "Invoke `f` with the first argument equal to `a` and the second argument equal to `b`".

Comment: Oh right duh. I am still getting the last error though.

Comment: @GuitarGuy365: The last error comes from the use of `elemIndex`. It returns a `Maybe Int` and not an `Int`, because there is the possibility that the given argument is not within the given list. If that is the case, `Nothing` will be returned, instead of `Just n`, with an integer `n`.